# Euclidean Norm of Curl / Divergence

Tags: divergence-operator, curl

Are there any general statements of the curl or the divergence of a 3-dimensional vectorial function, e.g. for the magnetic field:

$$|\nabla\times\boldsymbol B\left(t,\vec{x}\right)| = ?$$
$$|\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol B\left(t,\vec{x}\right)| = ?$$

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Well, we have that $\nabla \cdot \vec{B}=0$ from Maxwell's equations :)

Comment: True, but only if there are no magnetic monopoles ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates, we have that
$$(\nabla \times \vec{v})_i=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jv_k$$
So
$$\begin{align}
|\nabla \times \vec{v}|^2&=(\nabla \times \vec{v})\cdot(\nabla \times \vec{v})\\&=\epsilon_{ijk}(\partial_jv_k)\epsilon_{ipq}(\partial_pv_q)\\
&=(\delta_{jp}\delta_{kq}-\delta_{jq}\delta_{kp})(\partial_jv_k)(\partial_pv_q)\\
&=(\partial_pv_q)(\partial_pv_q)-(\partial_qv_p)(\partial_pv_q)\\
&=(\nabla\cdot v)^2-(\partial_qv_p)(\partial_pv_q)\\
&=|\nabla \cdot v|^2-J_{pq}J_{qp}\\
&=|\nabla \cdot v|^2-\operatorname{Tr}(J^2)
\end{align}$$
Where $J$ is the jacobian matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Instead, it should be:

$$
\begin{align}
|\nabla \times \vec{v}|^{2} &=(\nabla \times \vec{v}) \cdot(\nabla \times \vec{v}) \\
&=\epsilon_{i j k}\left(\partial_{j} v_{k}\right) \varepsilon_{i p q}\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right) \\
&=\left(\delta_{j p} \delta_{k q}-\delta_{j q} \delta_{k p}\right)\left(\partial_{j} v_{k}\right)\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right) \\
&=\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right)\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right)-\left(\partial_{q} v_{p}\right)\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right) \\
&=\sum_{p=1}^3\sum_{q=1}^3\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right)^{2}-\left(\partial_{q} v_{p}\right)\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right) \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}\left(JJ^\mathrm{T}\right)-\left(\partial_{q} v_{p}\right)\left(\partial_{p} v_{q}\right) \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}\left(JJ^\mathrm{T}\right)-\operatorname{Tr}\left(J^{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$